# Using solr 4.2 how do I use/enable fuzzy phrase searching

Tags: solr, lucene

So right now I'm just using the admin interface to run search queries. I know that a tilde ~ suffix causes a word to become fuzzy search.

However, what about a phrase? I tried "some words"~ but it doesn't seem to be returning results when it should be. Any idea why? Do I need a special fieldtype or special filters?

Right now, everything is pretty vanilla but I did import a lot of data. (About 12 million rows). I know that there are things in there that should be getting returned with a good fuzzy match that are not.

Any help is appreciated.

Also, if it makes a difference I would like to use the levenshtein algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser) can be used to handle wildcard and fuzzy phrase queries.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that ComplexPhraseQueryParser was for older version of Solr? That newer version had this functionality built in? I could be wrong.

Comment: ComplexPhraseQueryParser is still required to use such syntax in Lucene, as [seen here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html).  Personally, I haven't seen anything to indicate that SOLR has incorporated it into it's standard query parsing.

Comment: Well, if anyone can explain or know of direction for installing ComplexPhraseQueryParser with Solr 4.2 I would appreciate it. I can't find any documentation on it at all other than for the actual class file.