# Install ComplexPhraseQueryParser with Solr 4.2

Tags: solr, lucene

In reference to my other SO question ([Using solr 4.2 how do I use/enable fuzzy phrase searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626990/using-solr-4-2-how-do-i-use-enable-fuzzy-phrase-searching))

I was told I can get fuzzy phrases working by installing the plugin mentioned there (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1604). However, with every attempt I've made I cannot get it to work. When I download the latest dated file, there is not readme or install directions. Also, I'm not entirely sure that there is a version for Solr 4.2 yet.

Can someone provide me with instructions on how to install that plugin with Solr 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking at this myself. According to another SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463319/1222019) that parser was added in Solr 4.8, though it may be possible to add it to the solr war file in earlier versions and recompile.