# Using ComplexPhraseQueryParser in Datastax search

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I want to perform complex searches in Datastax search. On solr wiki page, it is suggested to use a complex phrase query parser to do the work (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser) However, the syntax did not work - so it seems i need to plug it in additionally.

I am using Datastax enterprise 4.5. Is there any particular procedure to plug in the parser - maybe put it in particular location and make specific changes to get it started?

Answer (score 0):

Complex phrase query parser was added in Solr 4.8.  DSE 4.5 and DSE 4.6 is on Solr 4.6.  DSE 4.7 (which is not available yet) will contain Solr 4.10 which will include the complex phrase query parser.

Comment: It is possible to add the following as a plugin: [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1604). The suggested procedure is to open the solr war file, put the class in and recompile it. I did not see a Solr war file in datastax. Any method to put it in and then refer the parser in solrconfig.xml